# Unattended AggCat API access

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I'd like to confirm my reading of the documentation for AggCat:

- Real-time API access with categorization requires a user token which expires in one hour
- If we want to refresh a customer's data behind the scenes, as an unattended process, we can use the Batch Data APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refresh the access tokens anytime you want, but they are always only an hour long.

Batch is only if you want to get categorization. Nothing to do with unattended access specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Mike,
You can refresh the access tokens anytime you want, but they are always only an hour long.

Batch will update the account transactions on a nightly basis and will generate a file that you can consume to capture transactions.  To download those files you will make use of the Batch API calls which also utilize the user token.  You can at anytime perform a real-time refresh on an account to capture up-to-date transaction information.  If you wish to have categorization that information will be available in both the batch file as well as the getTransactions API call.

regards,

Ben

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben! This is really useful info. Can't wait to try out the API, once somebody gives me access to it, that is :)